# Restrict a string literal union based on an other string literal union

Tags: typescript

I'm tracking user activity in my app and I'm using typescript to restrict which events can be tracked. First property is the name of the event, the second property (called `params: {[key: string]: string | number | boolean | null}`) is any combination of key value pair.

```
interface Event {
  name:
    | 'User Signup'
    | 'User Login'
    | 'User Logout'
    | 'Like Artwork'
    | 'Skip Artwork';
  params: {
    [key: string]: string | number | boolean | null;
  };
}
```

Then I can call my tracking function like so:

```
trackEvent('User Login', {
  user_id: 123
});

trackEvent('Like Artwork', {
  artwork_id: 456
});
```

Now I'd like to add some more constraints to prevent calling some events with the wrong set of params. For instance this should not be allowed:

```
trackEvent('User Login', {
  artwork_id: 456
});
```

Any idea how I can do this with typescript? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a type that maps event names to their params like this:

```
type EventMap = {
    'User Login': { user_id: number };
    'Like Artwork': { artwork_id: number };
};
```

then one option is to use generics so that the params are associated with the given event:

```
function trackEvent<E extends keyof EventMap>(event: E, params: EventMap[E]) {
    /** epic implementation here */
}
```

and now you get the desired behavior:

```
trackEvent('User Login', {
  user_id: 123 // OK
});

trackEvent('Like Artwork', {
  artwork_id: 456 // OK
});

trackEvent('User Login', {
  artwork_id: 456 // ERROR
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnbGaN)